# Is this possible in TestFlight?

Tags: ios, testflight

I currently have version 0.1 build 8 currently sent out. I am wondering if I reset the list and add users again, will only the new users get the latest build or will the old ones get it too? Say I push out build 0.2 or 0.1 build 9 and I only want users on the list getting that build.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. When you have want to test a new version, the older one cannot be dowload anymore by testers. However it doesn't erase or update it automatically.

If you want only a part of your testers to try the new version, change your list of testers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is yes -- *if* you can delete the old list then you will be able to do exactly what you want.

The alternative is know by Apple to be a mess -- if new stuff went to old users, how could you fire people?

Another alternative is to create a new app in iTunes Connect, but this is messy.

Answer (score 0):

I do this regularly. Remove the existing users from the build and Save. Add the new build, add the new users and Save. Only the new users will receive an invite to the new build and be able to install it.